# Error accessing a new 'My Site' site collection

Tags: 2010, permissions, my-site

I've created a new My Site Host site collection and have provisioned the User Profile Service Application.

When I attempt to visit the site as the site collection administrator, I cannot get access and receive a '403 Forbidden' message from the server.

Checking the log files, I find the following messages...

```
Failed to add the ghosted document with 0x80070050
Error importing WebPart. Assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, TypeName. Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.TagInformationWebPart
http://[my-site]/tagprofile.aspx - An unexpected error has been encountered in this Web Part.  Error: This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists., DesignText: <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">        <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>        <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.TagInformationWebPart</TypeName>        <Title>About This Tag</Title>        <Description>Displays metadata from a managed taxonomy about specific terms</Description>        <PartOrder>2</PartOrder>        <FrameType>None</FrameType>        <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>        <AllowRemove>false</AllowRemove>        <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>       </WebPart>, SourcePreamble: DWP
Leaving Monitored Scope (ErrorWebPart). Execution Time=10.6672775450511
Error importing WebPart. Assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, TypeName. Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.TaggedUrlListWebPart
```

Wondering if anyone can direct as to what to do next?

Comment: When you say visit the site, do you mean the my site host root site? Does your user have permission for this? Check your webapplication and set a policy for the user.

Comment: Hi, yes my site is at 'http://my.domain.com/'.  I visit this address in my browser and attempt to log in with the Site Collection administrator user.

Answer (score 1):

The tag controls will be dependent on the Managed Metadata service application. It might be worth checking that the Managed Metadata service is set up correctly in your farm?